# Multiple Process InitScript Logic

Tags: linux, redhat

I am developing initscripts for some of our software, and am having difficulty deciding how I should use it for a particular piece.

We have homegrown software responsible for passing data around out network, it's built on a standard pubsub model. There is a publisher process (two, actually, for two different use cases), a broker process, and a subscriber process). Any combination of these processes, and even multiple of the same process, can run simultaneously on a given box. I'm having trouble deciding how best to allow this to be configured. Since it can vary from box to box, that will likely go into `/etc/sysconfig/pubsub` which will be read in by the initscript.

The only things I will have to allow to be configured is (1) the process name, which is one of log_publish, dir_publish, broker, subscribe, and (2) the configuration file that corresponds to that particular process.

I wish to avoid telling people how to modify the initscript per box in order to change the list of running processes, so this unique configuration file per box is the best way I can come up with to accomplish that.

I assume this also means that I will have to have some kind of unique identifier per process on the box, as I intend to use the `touch /var/lock/subsys/*` method that most RedHat initscripts use already to lock a process from running twice. Knowing this, I know the identifier can't always be random, otherwise it will never be effective in order to prevent duplicate processes with the same configuration file (because, again, I need to be able to run multiple processes with different configuration files).

I have no idea how best to represent this in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this similarly to how VNC does it when run as an initscript.

If you look at your distro's configuration file for vnc init (ex. RedHat/CentOS: `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers`), you see this:

```
# The VNCSERVERS variable is a list of display:user pairs.
#
# Uncomment the line below to start a VNC server on display :1
# as my 'myusername' (adjust this to your own).  You will also
# need to set a VNC password; run 'man vncpasswd' to see how
# to do that.  
#
# DO NOT RUN THIS SERVICE if your local area network is
# untrusted!  For a secure way of using VNC, see
# <URL:http://www.uk.research.att.com/vnc/sshvnc.html>.

# VNCSERVERS="1:myusername"
# VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 800x600"
```

Pretty straight forward. You define a screen number, and parameters to match if necessary.

So now, I have, for example:

```
PUBSUBPROCS="1:publish 2:broker 3:subscribe"
PUBSUBARGS[1]="/config/publish.cfg"
PUBSUBARGS[2]="/config/broker.cfg"
PUBSUBARGS[3]="/config/subscribe.cfg"
```

And most all of the logic for parsing this was also ripped out from the vncserver initscript, which I will not post here for length reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say have multiple initscripts, one per process type, and then let the configuration for each determine how many of that process to spawn.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how best to manage configuring all these processes? Some kind of a helper script/app to generate the initscripts you need per box?

Comment: Just have all of them, and let people use chkconfig or whatnot to turn them on or off.

Comment: You missed the part where there may be multiple of the same process. So it's not as simple as "ship all 4 and let them choose". We have an (unfortunate) use case where one of our boxes has 7 or 8 publishers, and nothing else. Come to think of it, I actually completely forgot about the 5th process that exists, that we use on the same multiple publisher box.

Comment: "... and then let the configuration for each determine how many of that process to spawn."

Comment: So basically you're suggesting that... in `/etc/sysconfig/pubsub`, do something like: `PUBSUB_CONF="pub1.conf pub2.conf pub3.conf"` change the IFS to `" "`, and just iterate over the items?

Comment: If the configuration files are all going to be in the same directory then there's no need to enumerate them; the initscript itself can look at the files present and launch the appropriate processes.

Comment: Yeah, that's miserably unsafe, our configuration directory is miserable. I'd rather explicitly define them per my example. Not to mention, if it just reads in the configuration directory, there's actually nothing that maps a config file to a process, so that wouldn't work even if our configuration directories were less of a mess.